# drawing board using Canvas in html 5

Tags: html

How to create a drawing board / paint brush kind of application using Canvas in HTML5? I want an advance options like rectangle, circle, undo, redo, eraser etc.

Any help please?

Comment: Sorry, just googling found this http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2701/creating-a-drawing-board-using-canvas-in-html-5 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Try using [croquis.js](https://github.com/disjukr/croquis.js).

It has history functions(undo, redo), layer manipulation functions and nice brush implementation like photoshop, etc.

Here is [Demo](http://labs.crosspop.in/Croquispop/croquispop.html)

[image: brush-preview]